# Raspberry pi 3 (Stretch) no eth0

Tags: networking, lan, raspberry-pi, dhcp

After boot there is no eth0 device , no matter if cable is plugged or not!

Nothing in /var/log/syslog - no error ar anything about this interface.

```
$ rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

In /etc/network/interfaces

There is nothing , only commented lines.

Nothing in /etc/dhcpcd.conf either

In /etc/default/networking

```
#CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=yes
#EXCLUDE_INTERFACES=
#VERBOSE=no
```

Confusing for me is that i have another Pi with same options (network/interfaces, dhcpcd.conf) , but the other pi power its eth0 on startup and auto assign link local ip (169.254)

The problematic Pi does not seems to interact with eth0 at all.

What clue can you give me, where to look for this problem?

---

status of dhcpcd

```
dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

---

journal:

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 17:16:43 UTC, end at Thu 2019-08-01 14:00:02 UTC. --
Aug 01 13:56:01 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4481]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 01 13:56:01 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4485]: (root) CMD (/opt/check_lan/check_lan.sh >/dev/null)
Aug 01 13:56:04 wso-samsung-01 root[4492]: Network is up; clearing flag ...
Aug 01 13:56:04 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4493]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm -f /opt/check_lan/stuck.fflg
Aug 01 13:56:04 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4493]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 01 13:56:04 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4493]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 01 13:56:04 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4481]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 01 13:57:01 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4580]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 01 13:57:01 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4584]: (root) CMD (/opt/check_lan/check_lan.sh >/dev/null)
Aug 01 13:57:04 wso-samsung-01 root[4591]: Network is up; clearing flag ...
Aug 01 13:57:04 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4592]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm -f /opt/check_lan/stuck.fflg
Aug 01 13:57:04 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4592]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 01 13:57:04 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4592]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 01 13:57:04 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4580]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 01 13:58:01 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4681]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 01 13:58:01 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4685]: (root) CMD (/opt/check_lan/check_lan.sh >/dev/null)
Aug 01 13:58:08 wso-samsung-01 root[4693]: Network is up; clearing flag ...
Aug 01 13:58:08 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4694]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm -f /opt/check_lan/stuck.fflg
Aug 01 13:58:08 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4694]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 01 13:58:08 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4694]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 01 13:58:08 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4681]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 01 13:58:16 wso-samsung-01 sshd[4651]: Accepted password for pi from ::1 port 34710 ssh2
Aug 01 13:58:16 wso-samsung-01 sshd[4651]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
Aug 01 13:58:16 wso-samsung-01 systemd-logind[373]: New session c5 of user pi.
Aug 01 13:58:16 wso-samsung-01 systemd[1]: Started Session c5 of user pi.
Aug 01 13:58:26 wso-samsung-01 dhclient[563]: DHCPREQUEST of 172.27.0.129 on bat0 to 172.27.0.1 port 67
Aug 01 13:58:30 wso-samsung-01 dhclient[563]: DHCPACK of 172.27.0.129 from 172.27.0.1
Aug 01 13:58:30 wso-samsung-01 dhclient[563]: bound to 172.27.0.129 -- renewal in 262 seconds.
Aug 01 13:59:01 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4834]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 01 13:59:01 wso-samsung-01 CRON[4838]: (root) CMD (/opt/check_lan/check_lan.sh >/dev/null)
Aug 01 13:59:06 wso-samsung-01 root[4845]: Network is up; clearing flag ...
Aug 01 13:59:06 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4846]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm -f /opt/check_lan/stuck.fflg
Aug 01 13:59:06 wso-samsung-01 sudo[4846]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Comment: So what’s the output of `ip link`? All the resources you consulted are configuration files or show only wireless interfaces.

Comment: ip link

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000

i have it there , but no matter cable is plugged or not ... i dont see it in UP never, also i dont have any sign of it in syslog.  I have to manually up it: ip link set eth0 up ... then i see it in ifconfig results (even without cable)

Comment: So your interface is fine. Are you using an unmodified version of Raspbian? It *should* autoconfigure *all* interfaces by default. Please provide the output of `journalctl -S-5minutes` immediately after plugging and unplugging a (connected) network cable. Also provide the output of `systemctl status dhcpcd`.

Comment: edited the original post above

Comment: one more thing:  on the working device i have: Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter

after lsusb. on the problematic one - i dont. Is that a thing ?

Comment: I see you’re running `dhclient`. That’s not the default on Raspbian. I suggest you undo your customization in this case and re-enable `dhcpcd`.